# How to keep different currency for display purpose and transaction purpose in Magento?

Tags: magento, currency

I need to display store currency in pound.
but for payment gateway authorize.net, I need to do online transaction in dollar.
So We decided to set display currency pound and base currency dollar.

I have done like following,

Tab : `General / Currency setup`

`Base Currency` : US Dollar

`Default Display Currency` : British Pound Sterling

`Allowed Currencies` : US Dollar, British Pound Sterling

but in frontend dollar is displayed.

I have only one store. So what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

**you can use English language in magento.**

> Open lib/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml

find

> < currency type="USD" >

Add code 
:

> < symbol >£< /symbol >

before close < /currency>